# iOS UIAlertController appears bigger than normal

Tags: ios, ios8, uialertcontroller

I bought an iOS application template, but I was wondering why the UIAlertController and the status bar do not appear like normal. It appears bigger than the default design.

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: will you please post an image.....

Comment: Sounds like a question best directed to the person from whom you bought the template.

Comment: Can you please show the image or code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is not optimized to fit iPhone6/6Plus screen, then it's UI will behave as if it is iPhone5/5s and everything will look bigger than usual.
That might be the reason for zoomed status bar and UIAlertController.